# .htaccess to 301 redirect all ages to single page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found plenty of examples of redirecting all pages of a site to a single root, but they all involve switching from an old domain name to a new domain name.  I am using the same domain name, but have a site that used to have a bunch of pages but now is a single-page website.  So I want to match every old page and send traffic just to the root (which will serve the index.php file...but I don't want that in my URL).

So for example, each of these (there are really way too many to list manually):

```
http://www.website.com/oldpage/
http://www.website.com/page.html
http://www.website.com/stuff.php
```

Should 301 redirect to:

```
http://www.website.com/
```

Comment: Sorry I think I misread your question. Because the 2nd part of it confused me when you said `old site`

Comment: I re-worded it to now say "old pages" rather than old site.  It is all one domain name...but the pages that used to exist have now been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Justin Iurman

I got this working using your code...but yours was "too good" and was clearing my images anc css too!  Here is what seems to be working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
```